# Not receiving email Digital Ocean

Tags: email, digital-ocean

I set up my own email server on my Digital Ocean droplet, created A and MX records for it, but am not receiving emails at my email address.  How do I fix this so I receive email?

Answer (score -1):

The MX record needs a name in many cases - not an IP address.  Have two DNS records like below (wait 10 mins for any changes to propagate):

```
Type  Hostname               Value                 TTL
A     mail.[domainname.com]  [IP address]          3600
MX    [domainname.com]       mail.[domainname.com] 14400
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily setup mail client using 3rd party services too! For example : mailgun (https://www.mailgun.com/), mailchimp etc..

Easy to use and perfect for beginners.